# Xamarin application is not running on visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to mobile dev, so I started working on Xamarin forms.

I followed this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) demo, but I couldn't able to run the application as I get many error for `Animation`, I searched many articles and found that updating `Xamarin forms` will solve my problem.

So I updated it and after that all the other updates were removed and were on update panel in `nuget` like bellow

[image]

But when I update the above items, the Xamarin forms update is removed and is available on update panel

In either case I am getting error I don't know why

**Update**

I am getting error on this line

```
public static void UpdateIdValues()
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize = global::Phoneword.Droid.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize;
    }
```

Error is `Error CS0117  'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'`

Also see the bellow image it will show you at which emulator I'm trying to run my app

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Thats propably caused by using the wrong TargetSdkLevel. Please include the complete error message as well as your TargetSdk, MinSdk and CompileSdk-Level found in the project properties.

Comment: Latest Xamarin.Forms version depend on Xamarin.Android.Support.* 23.3.x , so updating to 23.4.x will uninstall Xamarin.Forms. So keep them not updated and let Xamarin.Forms pull in the dependencies it needs. As for the error you get, you need to be more explicit in how it does not run. Your question does not show any error messages or logs or stack traces.

Comment: Show the exact error message. This is not a site for guesswork.

Comment: I am getting this error **Error CS0117 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'**

Comment: Kindly see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

I haven't spent too much time with Xamarin, but in many cases I saw very similar behavior. I got around a problem by using the following approach:

- change the version of Xamarin.Forms until you find the one which is compatible with version of Xamarin SDK
- if you are currently using a version of Xamarin.Forms that is not compatible (i.e. you can't build or run your app), remove Xamarin.Forms and all the dependent packages that were installed
- never update packages that Xamarin.Forms depends on on their own (e.g. don't update Xamarin.Android.Support.Design separately of Xamarin.Forms even if Visual Studio shows you that there is a newer version of a package available)

Good luck!